# Center Align TextView in LinearLayout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to align textview to vertically centre respect to EditView

[image]

my layout as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="text1"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/setup_homeid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxLength="5"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint=""/>           
    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

how can i achieve it ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change this `android:layout_gravity="left"`

into this,

```
 android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
```

or

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

for your TextView.

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="text1"/>
```

Comment: left|center_vertical works perfectly I'd recommend that

Answer (score 3):

Add `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` to your TextView tag. Change your TextView tag as below

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="text1"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `center_vertical`:

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="text1"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I must set the weight property to 1 else the layout_gravity do not take effect.

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
      <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sampleId"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Center String"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:typeface="sans" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply change `TextView`'s `android:layout_height` to `match_parent`, this should do the job. Hope this helps.